# My service worker is not working as expected

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome, service-worker, chromium, service-worker-config

I'm using Service Worker in my React-JS project. Our project runs in 2 combinations of Browsers and an Operation System.

1. Chromium-102.0.5005.63 and Windows 7
2. Chromium-49.0.2623.75 and Windows XP

Service worker works fine in Chromium-102.0.5005.63 and Windows 7, but it's not working in Chromium-49.0.2623.75 and Windows XP, throwing the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property of 'set' of undefined
> ServiceWorker script evaluation failed

A few things to mention:

**1.** Project URL load under `https`

**2.** Chromium-49.0.2623.75 supports Service Worker as mentioned in the specifications

Reference 1: https://caniuse.com/?search=service%20worker

Reference 2: https://blog.chromium.org/2016/02/chrome-49-beta-css-custom-properties.html

**3.** "serviceWorker" in navigator returns `true` in Chromium-49.0.2623.75 and running on production mode

**4.** `browserslist` is updated and defined as follows in `package.json`

```
"browserslist": {
    "production": [
      "> 0.04%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
```

When I use `npx browserslist` I can see `chrome 49` in the list.

**5.** I'm not using any `.set` in `service-worker.js` and `serviceWorkerRegistration.js`

**UPDATE 1:**
`Cannot read property of 'set' of undefined` is caused by the following method in service-worker.js. `cacheKeyURL.searchParams` is undefined.

```
var REVISION_SEARCH_PARAM = '__WB_REVISION__';
/**
 * Converts a manifest entry into a versioned URL suitable for precaching.
 *
 * @param {Object|string} entry
 * @return {string} A URL with versioning info.
 *
 * @private
 * @memberof workbox-precaching
 */

function createCacheKey(entry) {
  if (!entry) {
    throw new WorkboxError_WorkboxError('add-to-cache-list-unexpected-type', {
      entry: entry
    });
  } // If a precache manifest entry is a string, it's assumed to be a versioned
  // URL, like '/app.abcd1234.js'. Return as-is.


  if (typeof entry === 'string') {
    var urlObject = new URL(entry, location.href);
    return {
      cacheKey: urlObject.href,
      url: urlObject.href
    };
  }

  var revision = entry.revision,
      url = entry.url;

  if (!url) {
    throw new WorkboxError_WorkboxError('add-to-cache-list-unexpected-type', {
      entry: entry
    });
  } // If there's just a URL and no revision, then it's also assumed to be a
  // versioned URL.


  if (!revision) {
    var urlObject = new URL(url, location.href);
    return {
      cacheKey: urlObject.href,
      url: urlObject.href
    };
  } // Otherwise, construct a properly versioned URL using the custom Workbox
  // search parameter along with the revision info.


  var cacheKeyURL = new URL(url, location.href);
  var originalURL = new URL(url, location.href);
 
  cacheKeyURL.searchParams.set(REVISION_SEARCH_PARAM, revision);
  return {
    cacheKey: cacheKeyURL.href,
    url: originalURL.href
  };
}
;// CONCATENATED MODULE: ./node_modules/workbox-precaching/utils/PrecacheInstallReportPlugin.js
```

You can see service-worker.js in here:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/13bESH2QRG-y_s5WyZjX51FjP-_kC8vmC/view?usp=sharing

**UPDATE 2:**
It seems the URL object works differently in chrome 49 and 102.
I added the following code manually to service-worker.js (inside the build directory) and I no longer receive the "Cannot read property of 'set' of undefined" error instead I get "ServiceWorker failed to install" and I have no clue why since there is no information provided.

```
var cacheKeyURL = new URL(url, location.href);
  var originalURL = new URL(url, location.href);

//This Part
  if (!cacheKeyURL['searchParams']){
    var urlParams = new URLSearchParams(location.search);
    cacheKeyURL.searchParams = urlParams;
  }

  cacheKeyURL.searchParams.set(REVISION_SEARCH_PARAM, revision);
```

By the way, How can I add "//This Part" to the original service-worker.js?

Can you please help me out?!

Comment: Can we see the actual service worker scripts?

Comment: This seems an issue with the code of the service worker and not the fact that you are using a service worker. Please include some [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) where you encounter the same issue so we can further debug.

Comment: Yep, seems like some JavaScript statements aren't supported in Chromium-49 or some APIs are not accessible from the service worker. You can find the statement that is not working and try to rewrite it or add some kind of a polyfill.

Comment: @hackape

Sure.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/13bESH2QRG-y_s5WyZjX51FjP-_kC8vmC/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm little late to answer, But I would like to extend accepted @M.H.'s answer

From the [mozilla-docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL) It states

> If a browser doesn't yet support the `URL() constructor`, you can access a URL object using the Window interface's URL property. Be sure to check to see if any of your target browsers require this to be prefixed.

And you are accesing the `searchParams` as `<URL_instance>['searchParams']`. This doesn't work on all scenarios, this works only when you have `key , value` pair.

So it is preferred to use the `.` dot operator.

Further from docs:

[image]

[image]

##### Both URL() and searchParams() has complete comptability over all the device.

Change your following code which fetches using `key`

```
 if (!cacheKeyURL['searchParams']){     instead of using the instance variable
    var urlParams = new URLSearchParams(location.search);
    cacheKeyURL.searchParams = urlParams;
  }
```

to use `dot` operator

```
if (!URL.prototype.searchParams) {      try to access using prototype 
   URL.prototype.searchParams = new URLSearchParams();
}
```

Hope it helps and adds more value to the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is `URL` prototype and `waitUntil()` In chrome 49

Add the following code to fix URL problem:

```
if (!URL.prototype.searchParams) {
   URL.prototype.searchParams = new URLSearchParams();
}
```

Use [async-wait-until](https://www.npmjs.com/package/async-wait-until) to run `waitUntil()` synchronously (instead of asynchronous)